# Tmux new-session returns: "can't create socket"

Tags: tmux, byobu

I have killed a `byobu` session accidentally (kill -9 byobuSessionId), and now when I try to start another `byobu` command fails with "can't create socket".

Also `tmux new-session` returns: "can't create socket"

I have tried `sudo service screen-cleanup start` without success !

Any idea how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem occurs maybe by dead tmux process if you check output for 
 ***strace -f -e trace=file tmux*** command.

You see socket file created by tmux, in my case is located on
*/tmp//tmux-1001/default/*

You simply delete this file and run again ***byobu*** command.

Answer (score 6):

Check the permissions of the `/tmp/tmux*/` directories. They should be owned by you and not accessible to anyone else.

So change permission as:

```
chmod 700 -R /tmp/tmux*
```

> It is important that the socket directory is owned by you and not
>   accessible by everyone, or any user could use your tmux server. For a
>   while, tmux incorrectly skipped the access mode check, this was fixed
>   in
>   2.0.
>
> If your system doesn't support creating directories in /tmp with the
>   right ownership, you will have to use -S to point it explicitly to a
>   socket. The check is important and we are not going to support systems
>   that do not have Unix file permission semantics.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and below is my solution:

1. Create a new folder: `/tmp/$(id -u)`
2. Change owner: `chown -R $(id -nu):$(id -nu) /tmp/$(id -u)`
3. Change permission: `chmod -R 700 /tmp/$(id -u)`

It works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it is because of disk space issue.

Answer (score 1):

on mac the those cmds did the trick:

```
sudo rm -r '/tmp/tmux-'$(id -u)
sudo chmod -R 4777 /tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission of `/tmp` may causes this problem.

You can check whether the permission of `/tmp` is `4777`, if not do this:

```
$ sudo chmod 4777 /tmp
```

Comment: `/tmp` should have 4777 (it needs the +t flag). Without it, everybody will be able to delete the files and rename the files or directories of the others below `/tmp`. Furthermore, it is a magician-like answer ("do X, you get Y" - but no explanation).

Comment: @peterh Thanks for reminding me for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the same issue on a shared server, where I had no special permissions outside my home directory. It happens that tmux was trying to access ~/tmp folder where to create its socket. That folder was not present and thus the error.

The solution on my case was to create the folder ~/tmp and all started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command `systemd-tmpfiles --create`. It creates some required folders under /run including tmux.

Answer (score -1):

Using command `strace -f -e trace=file tmux` you can see what files tmux called. Problem is ofted caused by permissions on /tmp folder.
On a standard installation of Ubuntu Server permissions are set to 777. You can change with

```
sudo chmod 777 /tmp
```